# how to show article preview in admin panel?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, component, extensions

I created a new article. I want to this article preview show only for admin not other user.How to do this? I used plugin "add menu" for this but that plugin not show my problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default you can't, maybe the most simple solution is via extension, try with
some extension like [Better Preview](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/article-preview/better-preview).

With this extension you can see the article before saving or publishing it, also
 you can restrict the access to the article in the back-end via **ACL**.

Here you have a complete tutorial: 
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the article and set Access = "Special" so that only Managers and Administrators can view the article in the font-end.

You can view the article in the front end by browsing to:

http://your-website.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=66

Change the article ID from 66 to the correct article ID which you can find in `Content -> Articles`.

Once you are happy for everyone to see the article, edit the article again and set Access = "Public".

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/10932

Refer this, apply the patch and you'll be able to view how your article would look like on your website. Not sure if it have user restriction like only admin can view or so.Hope this helps