# How do I preview an article in Joomla editor?

Tags: administrator, editor

How do I preview an article? In Wordpress, there is a Preview button which pops up a window with how the page looks. In the Joomla editor page, I see this, with no links to a preview.

[image]

I searched and found this link:

https://docs.joomla.org/Previewing_an_Article

It says

> After you have made changes to your content (if required) click the Preview toolbar button.

But I don't see a Preview button. I looked in the configuration for a setting, but I didn't see any settings for a Preview button either.

[image]

I found this answer: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/16131/11822

I installed Better Preview extension, but the editor page became broken.

[image]

When I click on the Preview button, that is also broken.

[image]

So how do I preview an article in Joomla? It doesn't seem like it should be this hard.

Comment: It looks like you're using a Yootheme Pro theme, which has it's own Page Builder built in, abstracting away from articles - a totally different setup for Joomla that's unique to Yootheme. That's likely why BetterPreview isn't working. I haven't moved to Yootheme Pro for this exact reason - it's takes away a lot of Joomla's flexibility. If you use a Yootheme theme that's marked 'Warp 7' this will work as you expect.

Comment: I should add that's in combination with the docs being wrong - nothing in https://docs.joomla.org/Previewing_an_Article applies to the Joomla 3.8

Comment: You can edit article in front, on save you return to your edited article

Comment: I have to clicked on 'Page Builder' to see a preview.

Answer (score 1):

Previewing an article is a functionality that was lost almost 7 years ago (beginning of 2011) when Joomla 1.6 was released (Joomla 1.5 supported previewing). So, now you have to resort to a plugin to preview articles, which may or may not cause conflicts with your template or with your whole website (in your case it is causing a conflict), not to mention, of course, that Better Preview has to load a standalone library in order for it to work (adding some overhead to your site).

I do remember experiencing a mysterious bug caused by Better Preview on one of our client's sites, and we communicated this bug to the developer via Twitter; his reply, to say the least, wasn't really nice.

The ideal solution, in my opinion, if you really need a preview functionality, is to add a special group/view level in your ACL called "Preview", and then assign your Joomla username to this group, and finally assign each article you want to preview to this view level first before assigning it to everyone. This is the lightest and most stable solution, and you don't need to install any plugin that may or may not break your site.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the "Preview" option in the "View" menu?

[image]

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot in the question there is no View menu.

Comment: Not using tinymce then?

Answer (score 0):

Use  TinyMCE Editor Plugin . This editor supports in joomla latest as well as old version.
Its a joomla free editor

Answer (score 0):

Check in the Global Cpnfiguration - Site Tab - Default Editor, choose one from the list.
TinyMCE is the default distrbuted with Joomla!